# How to inherit template in django asyncronously

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

How can I inherit blocks eg.(`{% block title %}{% endblock title %}`) in `base.html` without fully loading the entire page because my player always keeping stop wherever user try to do with other links.
What's an ideal way to achieve this.

I somehow able to load my **entire html asynchronously** but that didn't work.

```
function ajax_load_page(this_a_tag, to_page) {
    event.preventDefault();
    load_Page(this_a_tag, to_page);

};
function load_Page(this_a_tag, to_page) {
    fetch(`${to_page}`)
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(data => {
            document.open();
            document.write(data);
            document.close();
            window.history.pushState({}, '', `${to_page}`);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log("An error occurred:", error);
        });
};
```

**usage** in my html

```
<button class="nav-link active text-white w-100 text-start" onclick="ajax_load_page(this, '/')">
     <i class="bi bi-house-heart me-2"></i>
      Home
</button>
```

thank you!